# Illegal repetition near index error when using replaceAll in string

Tags: java

I want to remove the divPrefix string from request string, but I am getting "illegal repetition near index 142" error message. Could you please help to resolve this issue.

Note : This divPrefix is in the json request, so it will be there in multiple places. Is there a change to replace it in one shot?

```
String request="<div class="artemis-editor" style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 11px!important;"><style>.artemis-editor,.artemis-editor * {font-family:Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 11px!important;}</style><p>Paragraph content</p></div>";

String divPrefix="<div class="artemis-editor" style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 11px!important;"><style>.artemis-editor,.artemis-editor * {font-family:Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 11px!important;}</style>";

request=request.replaceAll(divPrefix,"");
request=request.replaceAll("</div>","");

Expected output:
<p>Paragraph content</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `replaceAll` method takes a regex as the first argument. You just want it to match a regular substring. For that, use [String.replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) instead.

Comment: You were correct about my answer.  So +1.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to replaceAll has to be a correctly-formed regular expression, not any old character string.  Your complex piece of HTML is not a regular expression.

It might be simpler to handle this 'manually' by using `indexOf` to locate the string you want to remove, and then `substring` to remove it.

[Documentation for String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Alternatively, and I have not tried this, consider wrapping the entire 'divPrefix' string in `\Q` and `\E`.

[Documentation for Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Personally, I don't like that approach; I find regular expressions to be somewhat overused, and in this case we are using a regular expression where we don't actually want a regular expression, so we're finding a way to make it be treated as 'not really a regular expression'.

Comment: I think you forgot about `.replace()`. Which is a better solution than 'use indexOf and substring together'.

Comment: @rzwitserloot - indeed I did!   It rather invalidates most of this answer beyond the explanatory first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the the replaceAll() function, you need to pass a regex(regular expression) as the first argument. For achieving your purpose, you need to use the replace() function. Modified code:

```
request=request.replace(divPrefix,"");
request=request.replace("</div>","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the *[String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))* method, and not the *[String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))* method.

The latter will interpret your argument as a *[regular expression pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.

```java
String request = "<div class=\"artemis-editor\" style=\"font-family:Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 11px!important;\"><style>.artemis-editor,.artemis-editor * {font-family:Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 11px!important;}</style><p>Paragraph content</p></div>";
String divPrefix = "<div class=\"artemis-editor\" style=\"font-family:Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 11px!important;\"><style>.artemis-editor,.artemis-editor * {font-family:Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 11px!important;}</style>";
request=request.replace(divPrefix,"");
request=request.replace("</div>","");

System.out.println(request);
```

Output

```
<p>Paragraph content</p>
```